# batch - copy files to few computers over lan

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I would like to copy \some\files to \computer1 \computer2 and \computer3 or better to c:\computerlist.txt

How to do some loops in batch files?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a copy utility called **xxcopy**.
it is a 'extended' version of windows's utlity xcopy.
Look it up on google, it has numerous options to copy files and folder.
It is free for personal use.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in (\\computer1 \\computer2 \\computer3) do (
copy some\files\*.* %%a
)
```

If you want to use a text file, then please provide more details about what you want to use it for.